# How to get these borders exactly aligned

Tags: border

I'm struggling to find out how to get the borders on the bottom and top of this bowties exactly aligned with those aside of it and stay the same when in different screen sizes.

http://www.muslimahwebdesign.co.uk/wac/home-copy/

I'm not sure if it's to do with the dimensions but I've tried everything and I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: Please provide code example in your question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem lies at the `div class="vc_item vc_active"`. Try changing the height there to match the others and see if that helps. If that doesn't help, at least that's where I would start from.

I can't help further as I don't see all of your code (maybe something else is breaking the page).

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image]

Hope this helps..